# TSQL: Count # of Failed Attempts on accounts prior to the 1st Approved Attempt BUT only if it happened after 2016-01-01

Tags: t-sql

Bit of a journeyman with SQL.

Trying to evaluate the number of Failed Attempts on accounts prior to the initial Approved Attempt using TSQL
BUT only those accounts that had the initial Approved Attempt after 2016-01-01.
Bit of a journeyman with SQL.

Made a number of attempts but with the number of self-joins that are required below (no way around them), I can’t figure out how to do it. Actually I’m not sure I’d know how to do it even with a simpler query.

```
   -->3 Failed in a 24 hour period (lifetime of account)
select count(distinct a.IDKey) AS Trans, '>3_Failed_24HRS_LIFETIME' AS TransTimeFrame
from (select tbdeg1.IDKey, COUNT(distinct tbdeg2.Transactionkey) as counters--, tbdeg1.TransactionKey
 from TEST.dbo.TBDEG tbdeg1
join TEST.dbo.TBDEG tbdeg2
     on tbdeg2.AccountID = tbdeg1.AccountID
     and DATEDIFF(dd, tbdeg2.entrydate, tbdeg1.EntryDate) between 0 and 1
where 1=1
and tbdeg1.EntryDate >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000’
and tbdeg2.EntryDate >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000’
and tbdeg1.TransactionType = 'Eval1'
and tbdeg2.TransactionType = 'Eval1'
and tbdeg1.TransactionStatus = ‘Failed’
and tbdeg2.TransactionStatus = ‘Failed’


group by tbdeg1.IDKey
having COUNT(distinct tbdeg2.TransactionKey) > 3) as a
```

Comment: What is the RDBMS you are using? Mysql and TSQL (used in MSSQL) are different platforms.

Comment: Yes, that was just a slip of the finger on my part. I'm using TSQL (MSSQL).

Comment: Full sentences better. *Bit of a journeyman* is irrelevant, and certainly didn't need to be repeated twice. Also, it helps if you include sample data and the output you're looking to obtain from that data along with your effort to produce the query, so we have a) a clear picture of what you're trying to do, and b) sample data to use for testing SQL before posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I think you're maybe running into some troubles because of smart quotes?  Or are those an artifact of pasting into here?

Next up, you *can* do this using a temp table, yes?  If you're using MSSQL, you can split this up so as to let you troubleshoot the inner part, thusly:

```
select tbdeg1.IDKey, COUNT(distinct tbdeg2.Transactionkey) as counters
into #preAggregateData
 from TEST.dbo.TBDEG tbdeg1
join TEST.dbo.TBDEG tbdeg2
     on tbdeg2.AccountID = tbdeg1.AccountID
     and DATEDIFF(dd, tbdeg2.entrydate, tbdeg1.EntryDate) between 0 and 1
where tbdeg1.EntryDate >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000’
and tbdeg2.EntryDate >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00.000’
and tbdeg1.TransactionType = 'Eval1'
and tbdeg2.TransactionType = 'Eval1'
and tbdeg1.TransactionStatus = 'Failed'
and tbdeg2.TransactionStatus = 'Failed'
group by tbdeg1.IDKey
having COUNT(distinct tbdeg2.TransactionKey) > 3
```

That should give you output something like:

```
| IDKey | counters |
--------------------
| Joe   |  3       |
| Jane  |  5       |
```

You can then examine the data by simply getting a count of the rows in that table, or by using something like:

```
select distinct IDKey
into #distinct
from #preAggregateData

select count(*) AS Trans, '>3_Failed_24HRS_LIFETIME' AS TransTimeFrame
from #distinct
group by '>3_Failed_24HRS_LIFETIME'
```

There's no need to do so, but you could drop the temp tables when you're done with them, or wait 'til the end of things & do:

```
drop table #distinct
drop table #preAggregateData
```